# How do I show the same Activity instance after the user signs in in a browser, without launchMode="singleTask"?

Tags: android

I have an Android app with a stack of activities. One of the activities in the stack (let's call it `LoginSettings`) needs to sign into an OAuth service. I've given it a button that launches a web browser via an `Intent`. `LoginSettings` can't use the `singleTask` or `singleInstance` launch modes, because it needs to stay on top of the stack of its predecessor activities. That is, if the user presses *back* from `LoginSettings`, the prior activity in the stack needs to show up, and if the user relaunches my app later, it can't relaunch showing the previous activity in the stack. Breaking the stack in the middle like `singleTask` does is no use.

I've used the web browser and the trick with a custom callback URL and intent filter, but because I can't use `singleTask`, I can't get the result into the same instance of `LoginSettings`: it always creates a new activity, even if the `launchMode` is `singleTop`. The desired behaviour is that after the user logs in, the browser window goes away and the user sees `LoginSettings`, still with the rest of the stack behind it.

I want to use the browser rather than a `WebView` to authenticate: first, because it shows the user they're genuinely accessing the target website, rather than giving my app their password; second, because the user probably has saved their password in the browser anyway (or may already be logged in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a useful trick. When `LoginSettings` starts the browser, it makes sure to add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to the `Intent` that launches the browser. (This probably won't make any difference, as browsers are `singleTask` anyway, but it's best to be sure.) Instead of giving `LoginSettings` the intent filter for my custom URL, I created a new activity. This new activity appears as a dialog, and doesn't have `allowTaskReparenting` in the manifest. It shows a progress bar and message while an `AsyncTask` goes and trades in the verifier for the auth token. When the `AsyncTask` completes, it calls `moveTaskToBack(true)` and then finishes. This moves the task containing (only) the browser and the dialog to the back, revealing the previous task, which contains my stack of activities leading to `LoginSettings`.

In my app, both `LoginSettings` and this new dialog use an OOB mechanism to talk to the class that actually manages and stores the auth credentials, so `LoginSettings.onResume` checks with the backend whether the user is now logged in, and replaces the login button if so. As an alternative, you could use a broadcast to communicate the login event, but don't forget that `LoginSettings` would be in the stopped state when the broadcast happens.

In theory, this could go wrong if the browser adds the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to the `Intent` it starts the custom callback URL with, but I've tested with Firefox and Chrome, and it works perfectly with them. Also, in theory, the task containing `LoginSettings` could be destroyed while it's in the background. This is a problem with solutions based on `singleTask` too: you need to be prepared for the callback URL to arrive via `onCreate` instead of `onNewIntent` if this happens. But with my solution, since the dialog completes the login and saves the credentials, when the user arrives back in `LoginSettings`, they'll be logged in even if the activity was recreated from scratch.